# Lenovo T420S WiFi where to find driver?

Tags: wifi, lenovo

Works fine with the latest Ubuntu. I found this on another search:

> The Broadcom wifi chipset requires a proprietary driver to work.
>
> Run these commands to install and enable it.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
> sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
> ```

But no joy- no wifi.

lsusb says broadcom BCM2045B (BCD-2.1)

Where can I find driver?

Comment: And what is the question? Because this is rather an answer.

Comment: While you can answer your own question, they should be separated.